# old project ZF2 - error in ServiceManager

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

We are trying to refactor and old ZF2 basecode to Laminas project, but we are failing to bring it up with the following error:

> [Wed Mar 24 15:16:57 2021] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message 'Zend\Mvc\Router\RoutePluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Zend\Router\Http\Literal' in /mnt/c/dev/onlinefieldevaluation/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php:555
> Stack trace:
> #0 /mnt/c/dev/onlinefieldevaluation/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/AbstractPluginManager.php(177): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('Zend\Router\Htt...', true)
> #1 /mnt/c/dev/onlinefieldevaluation/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Router/SimpleRouteStack.php(279): Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->get('Zend\Router\Htt...', Array)
> #2 /mnt/c/dev/onlinefieldevaluation/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Router/Http/TreeRouteStack.php(204): Zend\Mvc\Router\SimpleRouteStack->routeFromArray(Array)
> #3 /mnt/c/dev/onlinefieldevaluation/vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Router/Http/TreeRouteStack.php(154): Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\TreeRouteStack->routeFromArray(Array)
> #4 /mnt/c/d in /mnt/c/dev/onlinefieldevaluation/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php on line 555

I am using PHP 5.6.40. They use 5.6.19 in production.

**composer.json**

```
{
  "name": "OFE",
  "description": "Online Field Evaluation",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.5",
    "zendframework/zendframework": "2.5.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "0.8.*",
    "los/losbase": "~2.5",
    "los/losui": "~1.0",
    "zf-commons/zfc-user-doctrine-orm": "~1.0",
    "zf-commons/zfc-user": "1.*",
    "zf-commons/zfc-admin": "0.1.*",
    "zf-commons/zfc-rbac": "~2.4",
    "soflomo/mail": "dev-master#0da6f8a8e5d5520395554866bd33f27ab0a38362",
    "eye4web/eye4web-zfc-user-forgot-password": "dev-master",
    "components/jquery": "*",
    "components/jqueryui": "*",
    "components/normalize.css": "*",
    "malsup/form": "*",
    "twbs/bootstrap": "3.*",
    "neilime/zf2-twb-bundle": "2.4.0",
    "misarji/zend-oauth2": "1.0.0",
    "zendframework/zftool": "dev-master",
    "psr/container": "1.0.0",
    "koolphp/koolreport": "^2.42",
    "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "1.2.1",
    "phpoffice/phpexcel": "^1.8",
    "mvlabs/mvlabs-phpexcel": "^0.0.1"
  },
  "repositories": [
    { "type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/juriansluiman/Soflomo-Mail.git" }
  ],
  "require-dev": {
    "zendframework/zend-developer-tools": "dev-master",
    "los/loslog": "~1.0"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "framework",
    "zf2"
  ],
  "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
  "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
  "config": {
    "component-dir": "public",
    "discard-changes": true
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Comment: Zend\Router\Http\Literal is in your configuration probably, shouldn't it be replaced by Laminas\Router\Http\Literal or "literal"?

Comment: We have refactored the whole project to Laminas by now.